# Dell XPS 9310 2 in 1 will not suspend on lid close

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, xps, lid

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2, kernel 5.8.0-59-generic on an XPS 9310. I've come across a number of questions related to the *inability* to wake from a suspended state, but I'm having the exact opposite issue. Closing the laptop lid does not result in the machine suspending at all.

I took a look at the output of `sudo journalctl -b -u systemd-logind` and it appears like the lid closed signal is not being sent at all.

I also noticed that the option to suspend on lid close in the power menu does not in fact exist.

I'm at a bit of a loss for where to go next and was hoping that somebody else may have run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 If you’re using a desktop, tablet, or laptop, select Choose what the power buttons do. Next to When I press the power button, select Sleep, and then select Save changes.
```

If you’re using only a laptop, select Choose what closing the lid does. Next to When I close the lid, select Sleep, and then select Save changes.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, that option does not exist for me.